# How can we encourage posters to mention their country of study/work?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, localized-questions

[Academic systems and cultures vary widely between countries](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1212/7734), and answers will depend heavily on this context.

I have come across many questions, where the country has not been stated – presumably because it had not occurred to the poster that this information was relevant. Now one can of course ask in the comments to add this – but this causes a delay and gets a bit repetitive.

Is there a way to encourage posters to state the country which is relevant? I was envisioning something like a drop-down menu when asking a question, or at least a line reminding posters that it might be relevant.

Comment: A reminder seems to be a lot more likely to happen than a drop down but even if neither happens you can still comment on questions asking the user to specify their country in question.

Answer (score 7):

What we (or actually Stack Exchange employees) could do is to add a **tag alert** for tags that are prone to be country- or field-specific.

Tag alerts are special, tag-specific info messages that pop-up whenever the author adds certain tags to a question they are composing. To such an alert in action, begin [asking a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and add the SQL tag to it. You can read more about tag alerts on [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/2127008). I know that at least [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2353/19174) and [Anime & Manga](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1084/14905) also have tag alerts.

As for tags to which we could consider applying this, [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) and [phd](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phd) come to mind. In particular [graduate-admissions](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graduate-admissions) could do with a tag alert anyway, as I have the feeling that we are closing a lot of questions with this tag and a tag alert could help askers to ask appropriate questions or see that their question is not appropriate for our site in the first place.

Comment: Nice idea, I would also add alerts to the tags _cheating_, _interpersonal-issues_ and _sexual-misconduct_.

Comment: Hey there. We recently brought those up to the Ask Ubuntu community in [this meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14237/tag-warnings-on-ask-ubuntu), so there's more context there on how you might want to proceed.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: [For your interest](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/1886/7734). I do not think that *sexual-misconduct* is a sufficiently big tag to warrant the effort, though.

Answer (score 4):

Reminders don't work. On [CS Theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com), they modified the greyed-out text that appears in the subject line when you start a question, so it emphasizes that questions should be research-level questions about theoretical computer science. It made zero difference: they still get just as many questions about undergrad exercises and fixing Windows as they always got.