# Is it okay to ask this question?

Tags: discussion

I want to ask a question asking whether I should go for a PhD or not depending on many factors, if I ask this question would it be on-topic?

Comment: As long as you are _very specific_ what you want and what are your 'strengths' that people can accept you for, I don't see why not. However, it is likely such a question already exists. Also, advisors at your insitution can give way better answers that random people on the internet

Answer (score 8):

There are a few problems with such questions:

- There are really a lot of factors weighing into such a decision. It is very unlikely that you are able to accurately communicate all this information – mostly for the reason that a lot of information such as your skills cannot be accurately quantified or you do not even perceive it as relevant even though you subconsciously take it into account.
- Such decisions do not only depend on observables but also on how important you weigh your academic career, money, ethics, job security, family, and so on.

Therefore, we cannot and do not like to make such decisions for you. What we might be able to answer is what factors you have to consider, i.e., we can help you making a decision that is as informed as possible. However, at the end of the day you have to make the decision yourself.

Even then, a question asking for all factors to consider here is very broad. If you can, narrow down your question to some specific aspect that strongly influences your decision, e.g.:

> I want to do a PhD in underwater basket weaving, but I really don’t like to write longer texts. How relevant and prominent can I expect writing to be during such a programme?

Also see: [Why was my question put on hold for depending on individual factors?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734)