# If your essay limits 1500 words, can you just reference essay prompt without discussing it, then criticize it?

Tags: support, closed-questions, specific-question

Apology for [If your essay limits 1500 words, can you just reference essay prompt without discussing it, then criticize it?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153916). How can I edit it so it doesn't strongly depend on individual factors?

My question can assist and matter any university student writing essay with word limit!  Thanks.

### EDIT

I don't know why my question closed, but [these created:2y..](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=Votes&q=%5bwriting%5d%20created%3a2y..%20is%3aQuestion) open. Don't these depend individual factors? I want know for future so I don't downvotes and suspended!

[Graduate student with abysmal English writing skills, how to help](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/133068)
[Colleague blames me for not spotting typos when I only reviewed the structure and content](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/150600)
[How to deal with my PhD supervisors rudely critiquing all my draft papers?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/128037)
[How to write papers efficiently when English isn't my first language?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/127116)
[Should I cite a really bad research paper published in my small research area?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/117949)
[How to to deal with advisor's criticism of my writing?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/145912)
[How to improve scientific writing skills?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/117413)
[Advice on writing a research paper in a less time](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/122157)
[PhD Advisor is lying about funding and doesn't write their own grants](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/124458)
[Which could be considered an appropriate number of self-citations?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/153883) asked 19 hours ago.

Comment: Those questions (at least from the title) appear considerably different as they are about writing publications (not coursework) or are about conflicts with a supervisor (which cannot be answered by the supervisor themselves). Can you argue why any of these questions should be closed as per [the FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-depending-on-individual-factors?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: The essay prompt should be obviously incorporated (not copied) in your introductory paragraph. 1500 words is roughly 6 double-spaced pages, so there is plenty of room for a good introduction to the question at hand.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I'm not arguing they should be closed. I'm arguing mine is like them and mine can open too. How writing publications differs writing coursework?

Comment: *I'm not arguing they should be closed.* – Well, try to apply the arguments from the FAQ to those questions. If you conclude that they should be closed, [edit] your question to elaborate why and there is something we can explain or discuss. If not, you might understand the rule. But if you do neither, we cannot make any progress, because we do not understand why you fail to see the difference.

Comment: *How writing publications differs writing coursework?* – The criteria for publications are universal (with some minor dependences on field and some dependences on journal). The criteria for essays are made by the instructor.

Comment: I'd suggest editing the title of this meta post to actually reflect what the meta post is about, e.g. "My question about referencing an essay prompt was closed for 'strongly depending on individual factors'. How can I edit it to fix this?" Right now, this meta post is just titled identically to the question, which doesn't make it clear what this meta post is actually asking.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot. Your question is a textbook example of the point “Questions on your […] teacher’s preferences” in [the respective FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3407/7734). The only person who can answer this question is your instructor. Everything we can provide would be a guess, which may be misleading.

There is no generally valid answer to this question, except: “It depends on your teacher’s preferences and the context.” The close reason in question was made for exactly such questions.

Comment: I don't think my question is “Questions on your […] teacher’s preferences”"? My question can be generalized so it doesn't depend on teacher. Obviously if you spend 1500 words just regurgitating author, then you get low mark.

Comment: @ParkKiHyun: That wouldn’t solve the problem. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thanks again. Please see my edit post?