# Complaint about Academia Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, moderation

I had a falling-out with a professor last year, and the situation has been quite distressing for me. I'm trying to deal with the situation in real life, but so far I haven't gotten answers, so I was posting about it on Academia Stack Exchange. It was a complex issue; thus, it's not something that can be fully addressed in one post. As such, I've posted various questions relating to the matter; however, they weren't duplicate questions; each had a distinct topic and could be applied to various situations. However, I've been prohibited from posting anything related to it, and I don't feel one can be prohibited from posting about a topic unless that topic is offensive and/or unrelated to the stack exchange. (My issue is directly related to academia.)

Yes, I post about this a lot, but I haven't broken any stack exchange rule, so I wanted to complain about this.

Answer (score 24):

Yours is a rather unique case.

- Of your 26 questions, more than 15 reference the same conflict, and 14 had a negative total score.
- You have a received a cease-and-desist letter from the institution in question, and the professor in question has replied to your overtures through counsel only.
- You have received very clear, unambiguous advice from this forum: leave her alone and move on with your life. You have explicitly stated that you will not take our advice (in which case, why ask for more advice?).
- Indeed, your later actions (meeting new professors and asking them to relay messages to her) present a very worrying trend -- both in terms of your mental health and in terms of your legal exposure (neither of which are within our area of expertise).

As for "not breaking any stack exchange rule" -- this forum does not allow duplicate questions. Several users have suggested that many of your questions could be rewritten so as to avoid any reference to the above situation; this would be perfectly allowed. In fact, I explicitly suggested that you do this on one question [two months ago](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151900/can-suing-one-university-hurt-your-admission-chances-at-another), but you chose not to so until a week had passed and the question had been closed and heavily downvoted (perhaps the question could be reopened now, but that is up to the community).

Comment: @cag51- I just edited that post to remove the specifics of my situation.

Answer (score 14):

> It was a complex issue; thus, it's not something that can be fully
> addressed in one post.

Stack Exchange sites are repositories of *well-defined* and *virtually independent* questions and answers. They are not a good place to ask a long series of questions connected by a thread, and with little or vague differences from question to question.

Users cannot follow such a long thread, can hardly see the differences between the questions and vote to close, even more so if the questioner doesn't seem to follow the advice given in previous answers and comments.

> I don't feel one can be prohibited from posting about a topic unless that topic is offensive and/or unrelated to the stack exchange.

We're sorry for what you're going through, but you have to understand that Academia Stack Exchange is simply not suitable for all types of questions related to the academic world. It's really not meant to be so: there are academic questions we can answer and others we can not. In particular, see also [Why was my question put on hold for depending on individual factors?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/20058).