# Policy suggestion: No personal advice

Tags: discussion

After getting enough of these, I am thinking maybe having a blanket policy such as the following would help:

We do not offer personal advice.  Questions asking what to do in your own situation will be closed.  Questions about how specific courses of action will be responded to are acceptable only if they are written about a generic person (not you personally) and the situation is sufficiently common that general answers can be made.

Comment: We already have a close reason for individual factors. So at some level it is policy already.

Comment: What problem do you expect to solve with this?

Answer (score 6):

There is already a close reason which applies to the majority of those questions:

> #### Strongly depends on individual factors
>
> The answer to this question strongly depends on individual factors such as some person’s preferences, some institution’s policies, the exact contents of some work or the asker’s personal values. Answers to this question would be far too speculative, broad, or would **primarily** consist of: “It depends on X.” See [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406) for details. Note that questions on the rules of institutions that operate at national or international level are permitted.

If you feel there's a certain type of questions which is not sufficiently covered by this close reason, you might want to suggest another wording for it, because to me (admittedly, a lurker here and no expert) it seems to apply.

Comment: I am seeking a more restrictive policy than this.  In particular, I think it is beneficial to require people writing questions to write them in the third person.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: What would be the benefit of that? As far as I can see, it’s just making people jump through hoops and making questions and answers harder to read.