# Is academia the right place to get help for dealing with classmates?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-ness

I have an issue with someone in my group project (a non-ESL student who writes in broken English)

Is this the right SE for this? Is there even an SE for this?

Comment: Well, is this happening in an academic setting (college or university) or a school setting (high school, etc.)?

Comment: It depends on the issue. Interpersonal S. Exchange could also be good. But, please make absolutely sure you mention the country and culture this happens in.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft this is in a college

Comment: @MarkBiernacki: I see you took my suggestion. Let's see how it turns out, ISE is always exciting;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, questions about interpersonal interaction in the classroom or classwork should be discussed with the class instructor.  It *might* be appropriate to ask about here, but if you have not asked your instructor first, it would be reasonable for people to downvote your question for "not showing any research effort."

"requirements and expectations of students" are on topic, but "content of coursework" and "undergraduate culture" are off topic.

https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
[Why was my question put on hold for depending on individual factors?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3406/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-depending-on-individual-factors)

Comment: "should be discussed with the class instructor": That heavily depends on the culture you are in. Most instructors I know come to class, give their homework and go. Some answer emails with questions. They do not see (rightly or wrongly) themselves responsible for questions on Interpersonal interaction. "One member of the group does nothing for the projects." "That's your problem, don't bother me with this."

Comment: "They do not see (rightly or wrongly) themselves responsible for questions on Interpersonal interaction."  That's unethical negligence.  It's well known that if students interact without any guidance, race and gender disparities increase.

Comment: I disagree: That's just a different culture. Students are adults and as such are seen as themselves responsible. It's the same in other parts of adult life (and I must say that I believe most of my former student collegues to be better with "gender disparities" than any of my former professors). Anyway, whether this is right or wrong, it's the case that in some country, the instructor is not responsible.

Comment: @user111388 "Students are adults" True, but adults are often implicitly racist/sexist/etc. In my view, if you don't feel educating students not to be biased is part of an educator's responsibility, that is equivalent to saying bias is okay.  It's even more important if students are being harmed by bias.  I'm talking about ethical and professional responsibility, not what is written in a job description/contract.

Comment: This may be. But in the same way that nobody educates professors, politicians, blue collar workers, doctors etc about their biases and group work abilities, students are also not educated about them (in general). This is just not seen as part of university (in my region). My point is that your statement "should be discussed with the instructor" is not universally true.

Comment: "nobody educates professors ... about their biases"  That is not true at all.  I think your experience is unusual.  20 years ago it might have been typical.

Comment: Again, maybe in your region. I am an university level instructor myself - I had no information/class/whatever on how to teach/biases/whatever, and, sadly enough, I know I could get away with bad teaching if I wouldn't care.