# How does someone ask a good question on StackExchange Academia?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I like asking questions on random sites to figure things out and pick other people's brains, but I'm new to this site so I'm trying to figure it out so I don't get my questions shut down all the time.

Comment: Perhaps migrate / re-ask the question on the meta Academia site?

Comment: OK, I'll figure out what that is.

Comment: So what exactly is the Academia Stack Exchange supposed to be about?  Just the inner workings of academia?

Comment: @user60445 Yes.

Answer (score 6):

- Read [Welcome to Academia.SE](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se).
- Read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the help center.

Answer (score -4):

1. Go to top questions.
2. Sort by votes.
3. Read the highest rated questions and see what they have in common.
4. ???
5. Rep points!

Comment: The highest voted questions basically have in common that they were featured in "hot network questions" and got a lot of views and thus, a lot of votes. Not necessarily the best way to figure out how to ask a question.

Comment: Your answer explains why so many people have so much difficulty asking good questions on SE. They make invalid assumptions like "votes equal quality," and "if a tag exists, it means a question is on-topic."