# Why is this question about bullying still on hold?

Tags: support, moderation

I have tried to re-cast this question to make it more general, and less related to my own experience. Do I need to do something further to trigger a 're-evaluation'?

[What can be done about the problem of bullying in post-PhD academia?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/124452/what-can-be-done-about-the-problem-of-bullying-in-post-phd-academia)

Comment: I still think your question, per my comment, is more of a rant and prompt for discussion than a question; I don't feel any edits have addressed that and I don't see any easy path to do so, either.

Comment: Hi Bryan. Do you think bullying in post-PhD academia is a topic that can be discussed?

Comment: Yes, but SE is not a discussion forum.

Comment: Interesting. Telling that in many months of being here that had not become clear to me; I had seen this place as one to discuss the answers to questions.  I see how hard you must have to work to achieve even what is out there. Nonetheless, I accept it is true; I'll interact accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The edited question has two two related parts that make it broad

> What unique aspects of post- PhD academic culture allow bullies to persist?
>
> What can be done to end this?

Even if you split the questions, it is still very broad. A much better, but less general question, would focus on a particular type of bullying, or even single incidence of bullying, and ask something like, how/why did this happen, or how to avoid it in the future, or how to deal with the consequences. We have a lot of good questions about sexism and advisors "stealing" ideas that probably constitute bullying.

As it stands now, the question seems to be inviting discussion and is not a good fit for the SE format.

Comment: Interesting. So am I to understand that SE does not allow broad questions?  If so, that might fit well at https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1203/welcome-to-academia-se

Comment: Although two questions is not acceptable, two questions along the path of a single answer is something I see regularly here. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: To be clear, I'm not simply nitpicking here; I'm going to try to reformulate this question into one that can be asked here. I do think there is an interesting, fairly general question available in this space.