# Why this question is closed?

Tags: discussion

Reopen Request for this [Question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/134371/1015). Its not apparent why this question was closed in the first place.

Comment: It might be an idea to copy and paste the original post and place it here because users with less than 10K cannot see deleted posts. If this meta post is anything to judge by, I'd say lack of detail is at fault.

Answer (score 10):

I see the following problems with your question:

- It is not clear what exactly you wish to know:

  - Whether to do such an internship?
  - Where to search an institution for the internship?
  - How to contact somebody for such an internship?

  Please consider the following FAQ regarding this: ["Here's my situation, any suggestions?" is not an answerable question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1205/7734)
- It’s not very clear what kind of an internship you envision. For example:

  - Do you need funding?
  - Do you have any restrictions or preferences in terms of location?
- Your academic background is unclear.
  How far did your academic career go and do you want it to continue?
- Depending on the answers to the above, the answer to the question could depend strongly on your individual background, personal preferences etc. Please see [this FAQ](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3406/7734).

If you want your question reopened, please edit it to address the above as far as possible.